# Android gms ImageManager never loads image

Tags: android, io, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm attempting to draw an icon for an achievement using Google Play Game Services API. 
However, it is silently failing.

#### Approach/Issue:

- The URI for the image is retrieved successfully, exists and is valid.
- I use `ImageManager.loadImage` to get the image, with an `OnImageLoadedListener` for callback ([`com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html)).
- However ***OnImageLoadedListener*'s method, *onImageLoaded*, is never called.**
- No error's, no evidence, just completely ignored, I even waited 10 minutes just in case.

#### Code:

```
// Get URI [is valid, exists, is of type png, I checked]
Uri uri = getAchievementIconUri(id);

// Use ImageManager to get the icon image
ImageManager.create(context).
    loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageLoaded(Uri u, Drawable d, boolean r) {

            /* 
             * This code is never reached, no call to onImageLoaded is made!
             */

        }
}, uri);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's probably a very late answer, but it might help other people experiencing the same. From the latest google documentation, https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html#public-methods

> Note that you should hold a reference to the listener provided until the callback is complete. For this reason, the use of anonymous implementations is discouraged.

This might explain the behaviour you experienced, as in the first code snippet provided, no reference to the Listener was retained.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it matters, I never solved the problem entirely.

It seems that it actually displays the icons occasionally, whenever it feels like it.

I implemented a workaround that loads a compressed, cached version of the image and later replaces it with the ImageManager provided image if it can be bothered doing so.

If anybody works out the correct answer then I will remove this workaround, but until then its here for anybody with the same issue.

#### Code that loads the local icons:

```
public Bitmap loadDefaultAchievementIcon(final String id) {
    // Get drawable ID for achievement
    // iconIdMap is a map of achievement ID strings against their drawable res IDs
    int resID = iconIdMap.containsKey(id) ? iconIdMap.get(id) : 
            // Fallback/unknown icon
            R.drawable.ic_action_achievements;

    // Load and return bitmap
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: It's really killing me. Have you ever happened to know why the listener is working so unexpectedly?